# django __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content'

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new with django and I'm making small SNS program

I build models and forms like below,

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class modelSNS(models.Model) :
    content = models.TextField(blank = True)
    password = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 10)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
```

> forms.py (I created this file)

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import modelSNS

class SNSForm(ModelForm) : 
    class Meta : 
        model = modelSNS
        fields = '__all__'
```

and views.py of my app is like below

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from MySNS import models
from .forms import SNSForm
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def SNS_view(request) : 
    content = None
    date = None

    if request.method == 'POST' : 
        form = SNSForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() : 
            form = SNSForm(content=request.POST['content'], password=request.POST['password'])    
            #^ error occur in this line
            form.content = request.POST['content']

            form.save()

        print(form)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/SNS/')

    else : 
        form = SNSForm()


    return render(request, 'SNS.html', {'form': form, 'content' : content, 'date' : date})
```

last, my html codes are here

> SNS.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SNS</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

<p><label for="content">Content : </label><textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea></p>
<p><label for="password">Password : </label><input type="password" id="password" name="password"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

<br/>
<h2>TimeLine</h2>

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to fill textfield 'content' and 'password', and POST them with clicking 'submit' button

then save and print articles on my page.

but when I submit data, django raise TypeError.

I'm studying django by myself and it's so suffering for me.

please tell me why this error happens and give me some advice

little comment will help me a lot

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you creating the `form` again? BTW, that is not how you create the form object. The first way is fine, where you just pass `request.POST` param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such argument called `content` in Form.

If you want to pass the POST data to django forms, you either pass it as the first positional argument, like this:

```
form = SNSForm(request.POST)
```

Or explicitly pass keyword argument named `data` to `Form`, like this:

```
form = SNSForm(data=request.POST)
```

When you call `form.is_valid()`, the data is already populated in the form attributes. There is no need to pass individual field values like `content` and `password` to the form.

Django's `forms.ModelForm` will populate the values of `content` and `password` by itself using `request.POST`.

All you have to do is:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect('/to-other-page/')
```

Comment: I misunderstood some  basic concepts of models and forms
your comment helps me a lot!
thank you!